# UDP: Question on how receiving responses work

Tags: java, sockets, udp, response

I am trying to make a simple udp server which receives 4 packets at the same time. I am wondering how socket.receive(packet) works in this case. Does .receive(packet) only take the first packet in buffer, process it and then move on to the next packet in buffer or are we dealing with synchronization here were all packets may be received at once? I have tested this with a simple String message and it appears .receive is processing one packet at a time, but I want to make sure this is the case.

Comment: What do you mean with "at the same time"? If they're separate packets, you receive them separately. Moreover, UDP is an unreliable protocol that does not sequence packets, so packets sent "at the same time" may be received at different times, or not received at all.

Comment: Say the 4 servers sending responses have the exact same code. That is they both are run at the same time and they execute the same instructions. Ie my question is what happens with .receive when the rate at which packets come in is greater then the rate at which a process can receive them

Comment: You will receive one datagram at a time. If the transmit rate exceeds the receive rate, datagrams will be dropped.

Comment: You receive them one at a time. "Unreceived" packets are buffered up to a limit - when that limit is reached, you will lose new packets coming into the computer. The limit is configurable both using `DatagramSocket.setReceiveBufferSize` (which is a hint to the OS, not a guarantee) and in an operating-system specific way. See this article for help for several operating systems: https://medium.com/@CameronSparr/increase-os-udp-buffers-to-improve-performance-51d167bb1360